# Why is React Toastify is Display HTML text

Tags: reactjs, next.js, toast, react-component

I am working on a react project and i used React toastify component.
when i call the toast, it does appear exactly where and how i want it to appear, on the top right corner of the screen.

BUT! There is some text that appears in the location where the code i wrote for calling the toast is.
I hope i make sense. Let me illustrate.

[image]

As you can see, the toast appears properly, but there is some text on top of my form.

```
return (
   <div>
       <ToastContainer />

       {success && toast.success(successMessage)}
       {error && toast.error(errorMessage)}

       {signupForm()}
   </div>
)
```

And it seems this text is sitting exactly in relation to my code, where the toast is being called.
Maybe im missing something very silly here. but i need help

Comment: What is that text? It looks random. Is it just coming out of nowhere or is it an input from you?

Comment: its not an input from me. its comming out randomly. and it changes everytime the application loads

Comment: The best way is to inspect the element from your browser to see what's going on.

Comment: ive been inspecting. The only thing i see is that text. No html tags or anything like that. That text just pops out out of nowhere. its really frustrating.

Comment: What do you mean no html tags? The text is a DOM element and there should be a tag enclosing it. Can you highlight the text in the inspector? If you can, can you inspect its `position` attribute?

Comment: I see what you mean. So when i inspect it, its position is in the same place where i call the toast. It  seems like the code i write to call the toast gets converted into that text. Look at the bottom image on my original post where i call the toasts

Comment: Normally these "toasts" are absolute-positioned, so whatever that text is it is part of the root element (although it appears far away). I don't see anything suspicious in your code though. Can that random text be that `message` variable's value?
Also it's helpful to post code as a snippet here, not image capture.

Comment: I think when i call the toasts using toast.success() or error, the toast does pop up, but i think that call leaves a trail, maybe its the id of the toast at the time its called. Thats the only thing that makes sense to me right now.

Comment: And thanks for the tip about writing code... its noted

Comment: Hey, I finally found out where i went wrong. You can check out my answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally found an answer to my own question. I'll just post it here just in case someone else run into the same problem.

I made the horrible mistake of calling my toasts inside of my return of the actual component. What I should've done is, call the toasts within my logic.

When i call the toast where i return my component, The toast becomes part of my component. And the toast's ID gets displayed.

For example...

```
        apiCall().then(response => {
            if (response.error) {
                toast.dismiss();
                toast.error(response.error);
            } else {
                toast.dismiss();
                toast.success(response.message);
            }

        });
```

As you can see from my code, I am calling the toasts inside my logic immediately when I encounter the error or the success.

Comment: I suggest you post a snippet to share with others and accept your own answer as a good practice.

Comment: Okay. I've accepted my answer as good practice. As for the snippet, do you mean i should edit my answer with the relevant code?

Comment: Yes, having clear, reproducible snippet makes it more helpful for others with similar problems.